# Include Children In WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, comments

I need to include children comments (replies) to comments which I'm filtering with a meta query.

If I'm filtering comments that have a rating 3/5, I need to include their children with the query (even though the children don't match the meta query).

```
$comments = get_comments( array (
    //'meta_key' => 'rating',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post_id' => $_POST['post_id'],
    'status' => 'approve',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'rating',
            'value' => $_POST['rating']
        )
    )
) );
```

Is there a way to "force include" children that don't match initial query?

(To see the issue live, try to filter the reviews by 3 stars on this page, and notice how the review reply is *not* included in the filter: https://herbalnitro.com/product/extreme-energy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you get the only comment with specific meta but children comments do not inherit this meta obviously. So you need to do it in two steps: 1) get comments with meta. 2) get children comments for a parent with which is with meta.

```
// get comments with meta
$comments = get_comments( array (
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post_id' => $_POST['post_id'],
    'status' => 'approve',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'rating',
            'value' => $_POST['rating']
        )
    )
) );


// find children comments
$comments_children = array();
foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
    $comments_children += get_comments(array('parent' => $comment->comment_ID, 'status' => 'approve', 'hierarchical' => true));
}

// combine all comments
$comments = array_merge($comments, $comments_children);

// print comments template if needed
wp_list_comments(array(), $comments);
```

Comment: I had high, high hopes, but unfortunately that didn't work. Hierarchical by default is 'threaded', which should show the children.

Also, it appears that (according to the Codex), hierarchical is an argument of get_children--not get_comment.

Comment: @Poocey You are checking outdated codex. To be sure that get_comments has a threaded argument you can simply open WP_Comment_Query Class and check. Here is a link https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8656a65e1ee657f0403921787a1862d11ca24019/wp-includes/class-wp-comment-query.php#L132-L303

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I set 'hierarchical' to 'threaded', but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: @Poocey I have edited my answer. I have tested it and it works as you asked for :)

Comment: You're brilliant! Thank you so, so much!